# loading audio driver available in R

Tags: r, audio

I am running "audio" package in R on my MacBook, and I can't get the default audio driver from the following code:

```
library(audio)
audio.drivers()
[1] name        description current    
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

I am trying to load an audio-driver using load.audio.driver(). 
But it is not working. 
Can you give me an example to load the audio driver.

I also tried to run

```
load.audio.driver("/Users/sourish/Music/iTunes/iTunes Media")
```

But I got this error

```
Error in load.audio.driver("/Users/sourish/Music/iTunes/iTunes Media"):
cannot load '/Users/sourish/Music/iTunes/iTunes Media' dynamically
```

Also tried this but did not work:

```
load.audio.driver("/Applications/iTunes.app/Contents/MacOS/libgnsdk_sdkmanager.1.9.5.dylib")
Error in load.audio.driver("/Applications/iTunes.app/Contents/MacOS/libgnsdk_sdkmanager.1.9.5.dylib") : 
specified module is not an audio driver
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On a Mac OS I installed audio library and I got the following:

```
> audio.drivers()
    name                  description current
1 macosx AudioUnits (Mac OS X) driver    TRUE
> current.audio.driver()
[1] "macosx"
```

I would check your install of the audio library since it appears that `audio.drivers()` is not finding any drivers which would lead to the next error of not being able to load any drivers.